# How to create a transparent PlaybackControlsRow leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want transparent `PlaybackControlsRow` background instead of colour one I've tried setting the background colour to #00000000 but it shows some grey background. In the below image I want transparent colour instead of green.
[image]

Comment: Did you try: `@android:color/transparent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that via overriding their color here `<color name="player_controls_background">#6600FF00</color>` and just making sure to add in the alpha to the color (the first two numbers of the hex are the alpha, the remaining numbers are the color hex).

They also have a shadow overlay on the controls which skews color. If using the above line doesn't look right, you can turn off this shadow by overriding their dimen `<dimen name="lb_playback_controls_z">0dp</dimen>`.

Please let me know if that works for you.